# Align text within div tags

Tags: html, css

I've this below html

```
str+="<div class='label' date1='"+a+"' date2='"+a1+"' id='mydiv'> Start Date "+a;
str+="End Date "+a1;
```

Now I want date1 should be aligned left to the page and date2 should be aligned right to the page.

How to do this?

Regards

Comment: wrap your  end date with `span ` tag and make it `float:right`. set your `div` width to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple with `flexbox` and `pseudo elements`.

```css
#mydiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#mydiv::before {
  content: "Start Date: " attr(date1);
}
#mydiv::after {
  content: "End Date: " attr(date2);
}
```

```html
<div class="label" date1="10/5/2016" date2="10/20/2016" id="mydiv"></div>
```

So, your code will be like this:

```
str+="<div class='label' date1='"+a+"' date2='"+a1+"' id='mydiv'></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xjr9m0Lj/)**

CSS:

```
.fl{ float:left; }
.fr{ float:right; }
.label{ clear:both; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="label" date1="10/5/2016" date2="10/20/2016" id="mydiv">
    <span class="fl">Start Date 10/5/2016</span> 
    <span class="fr">End Date 10/20/2016</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna save your time

///HTML

```
<div class="label" date1="10/5/2016" date2="10/20/2016" id="mydiv"><div style = 'float:right'>End Date 10/20/2016
</div>
</div>Start Date 10/5/2016></div>
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c6wnsob6/3/

Answer (score 0):

wrap the dates in `span` and add css as below

```
<div class="label" date1="10/5/2016" date2="10/20/2016" id="mydiv">
    <span class="float-left">Start Date 10/5/2016</span>
    <span class="float-right">End Date 10/20/2016</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.float-left{float:left;}
.float-right{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this codepen [codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/zKWjvL)..

I wrapped two dates in two spans and used `display: inline-block;` to the span elements to align inline with width and for the first element i used `text-align: left;` to start from left and for the second element used `text-align: right;` to start from right.

**Note:** I given `max-width: 800px;` to the parent element but you can give your width or you can remove.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually i am creating a dynamic label on click. So can u tell me how to align those tags..i have updated my code..

Comment: while creating label dynamically create span elements too at the same time as child's.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the both dates in **span** or **p** tag and make one element float to left and other to right.

UPDATED as per your code

```
 $str .="<div class='label' date1='".a."' date2='".a1."' id='mydiv'><span style='float:left'> Start Date ". a.'</span>';
$str.="<span style='float:right'>End Date ".a1.'</span>';
```

Comment: According to the updated code, how to concatenate span tag with str+...

Comment: @learningmode see now . I just used your way as you used + so just gone with that flow forgetting it that its wrong way

Comment: I am getting error ----Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: @learningmode code you provide is incorrect str needs to have $ sign as they are variable.

Answer (score 0):

use float:left and float:right for dates.

```css
.label {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.date-1 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  float:left
}
.date-2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="label" date1="10/5/2016" date2="10/20/2016" id="mydiv"><span class="date-1">Start Date 10/5/2016</span><span class="date-2">End Date 10/20/2016</span></div>
```